# User profile update author

Tags: email, profiles, notifications

So I'm trying to create email notifications to certain users to update them on updates to user profiles.  I'd like to send these users the profiles that were updated, and also which user made these updates.  Sometimes administrator-level users may make changes to other user profiles.  I know I can hook into the profile_update to send emails when an profile is updated, but the big question is how to get information on who made these profile updates?

Any suggestions on how to do this would be appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`wp_get_current_user`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_current_user) used inside your hook callback should tell you who is making the edit.

```
$editing_user = wp_get_current_user();
```

Without code, that is all I've got.